# Controlling WF persistence points transactions

Tags: c#, transactions, workflow-foundation

I am using WF, and need to support transactions and persistence.
I would like not to use the TransactionScopeActvity , but use my own transaction scope object, and still have a persistence point at the end which will be part of the transaction in the activity itself (similar to how the TransactionScopeActvity works on this aspect). I can achieve a persistence point at the end of the transaction by using the "PersistOnClose" attribute, but to what transaction will the persistence call belong to? will it open a new transaction, or look for the ambient transaction? How can I assure that an ambient transaction exists when the persistence point is activated?

Answer (score 0):

Version 3 and 3.5 **does not support ambient transaction** I faced a lot of Issues designing around this In the new version of workflow i.e. 4.0 (which is complete rewrite from ground up ) supports Ambient Transaction